# android tv can not receive fcm messages when device in standby

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-tv, television

As we know, tv has no system bar, so I just send data only messages, it works when messaging app is in foreground, background and even not runnning. But When I press "Power" key (with power instant on), the device will enter standby mode(str standby), I can promise the message has sent successfully:

```
{
 "to" : "xxx",
 "collapse_key" : "tv",
 "priority": "high",
 "content_available":true,
 "data" : {
     "body" : "wake up"
 }
}

{
    "multicast_id": xxx,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I can see the log:

```
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.tcl.fcmapp (has extras) }
```

When tv is in standby, I wake up the device by calling method like below:

```
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        wakeUpScreen();
    }
}

private void wakeUpScreen() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock
            (PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "LiveTV");
    wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);
    try {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have read the docs about FCM, it says FCM support wake up the device, so is there anything wrong with my using ways?

Comment: Just to clarify are you testing a TV with Android built-in or a Android TV box which connected to a TV screen?

Comment: A tv with Android built-in, and the OS version is Android 8.0.

Comment: Hi @coder.john , at the end, could you wake up your device in standby mode?